# PrivateRoute rendering the blank page ...showing no errors in react js

Tags: reactjs

**routing_page..
i used 2 switch statement first for Route and second for PrivateRoute..
and after login and getting token in local storage....when i visit to the privateroute it shows blank page only.....**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import LoginPage from "./Pages/Login_page";
import {Route,Switch,BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import SignupPage from "./Pages/signup_page";
import Noting_page from "./Pages/home_notingPage";
import INdividualNotes from './Pages/allNotesOfUser';
import Editing_page from './Pages/editingPage';
import PrivateRoute from './components/private';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/login"><LoginPage/></Route>
    <Route path="/signup"><SignupPage/></Route>
    <Switch>
    <PrivateRoute path="/notes" component={INdividualNotes}/>
    <PrivateRoute  path="/home" component={Noting_page}/>
    <PrivateRoute path="/login/edit" component={Editing_page}/>
    </Switch>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Private.js
i am using token here for auth**

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import  React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route ,useHistory,Redirect, useLocation, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
function PrivateRoute({component:component,...rest}){
    return(
        <Route {...rest}  
        render={ props=>
            localStorage.getItem("token")?
            <component {...props}/>
              :
            <Redirect to={{pathname:"/login",state:{from:props.location}}}/>
         } />)
}
export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is something related to the naming convention of components. Your component is written in small letters. If you just change {component: Component} in PrivateRoute file and then where you using your component `<component>` replace this with `<Component>`, It will render the page. Perhaps it is not mentioned anywhere in official docs or maybe it is happening due to react-router plugin.

Comment: Thanku .... it Worked....Litreally i searched everything but ...my mistake is just naming fault....

Comment: Kindly mark is as right answer if it helped you.